# Delete prefix from multiple variables

Tags: sql, sas, prefix

I have a dataset "Dairy1" with variables labeled as '240, 241, 242 ..." but the actual name is '_240, _241, _242 ...'.

How can I delete the prefix "_" from the name of all these variables? I tried to use the following code in SAS 9.4 but it doesn't work.

```
**proc sql noprint;
select cats(name,'=',scan(name, 1, '_'))
into :suffixlist
separated by ' '
from dictionary.columns
where libname = 'WORK' and memname = 'Dairy1' and '240' = scan(name, 2, '_');
quit;
%put &suffixlist.;
data want;
set Dairy1;
rename &suffixlist.;
run;**
```

It shows me the following:

WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference SUFFIXLIST not resolved.
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: un nombre, ;.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Am I correct, you can use SQL SERVER code right?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it

Comment: this '240' = scan(name, 2, '_') does not seem right

Comment: You can't have SAS variable names beginning with a number.

Answer (score 0):

I did similar solution the other way around, which added suffix to variables.
What this does, is to create single string, which contains all the variable rename-commands.

Note that this is a bit stupid as it will remove all characters. Just modify the logic to suit your needs in **data sjm_tmp2**.

```
%macro remove_str(Dataset, str);

    proc contents noprint
        data=work.&dataset out=sjm_tmp(keep=NAME);
    run;

    data sjm_tmp2;
        set sjm_tmp;
        help= tranwrd(NAME, "&str.", '');
        foobar=cats(name, '=',help);
    run;

    proc sql noprint;
        select foobar into :sjm_list separated by ' ' from sjm_tmp2;
    quit;

    proc datasets library = work nolist;
       modify &dataset;
       rename &sjm_list;
    quit;

    proc datasets library=work noprint;  
        delete sjm_tmp sjm_tmp2 ;  
    run;

%mend;
```

Tested with code:

```
data test; 
    _a=1; 
    _b=1; 
    _c=1; 
    _d=1; 
    _e=1; 
    _f=1; 
run;

%remove_str(test, _);
```

Comment: Whilst this solution will work for variables beginning with an underscore followed by alpha character, it won't work in the example given, nor will any solution for that matter, as SAS variables can't begin with a number.

Comment: @ChrisJ Oh. Right you are. Well, I don't see no direct answer then. With tested set it works ok, so I'll leave it there for someone to maybe use at some date.